# Javascript Logging function

Tags: javascript, logging

For a little project I'm coding besides my job I wanted to make a log function so I can output simple things into a textfile like the user input and possible errors that occured.
I wanted to make this log a simple .txt.
The problems I ran into were the following:
I want to check if the file already exists if not, create a new one; 
Then when the file exists I want to write below the existing contents. 
This is what I got so far:

```
/*
    Form:
    \r\n 
    \r\n *** logged (<dd.mm.yyyy> || <hh:mm:ss>) ***
    \r\n
    \r\n <pMessage>
    \r\n
    \r\n *** log end ***

 */
function log(pMessage)
{
    var logPath = "../../Logs/SiteLog.txt";
}
```

I know it is not much because I haven't done anything there yet. So i basically need three things: Checking if the file exists, creating a file, editing the file.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using NodeJS or the browser? For security reasons browser run  JavaScript doesn't have permission to modify the file system. If NodeJS, check out https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: When you search on Google for something like "JavaScript write to file", what do you find?  Anything at all?

Comment: In browser. Only for my own testing. This is a private project I'm using to expand my horizon. I already googled and found some things. The thing is I didn't understand most of it. I'm pretty new to using js in this way. I got into it about half a year ago when I started my job as a frontend developer. Our program already has a massive backcatalogue of libs so I didn't have to write stuff like this on my own so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is client side, the browser will prevent you from writing to the file system. If this is strictly for your own testing purposes locally, you could write to window.localStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

This would allow you to read and write from a local storage that the browser caches based on domain

```
function read (name) {
  return window.localStorage.getItem(name)
}

function write (name, value) {
  var report = window.localStorage.getItem(name) + '\n' + value
  window.localStorage.setItem(name, report)
  return report
}
```

Comment: I'm using it in my browser but only for testing. I'll test this, thanks.